# Why can't I see my image in my Image container from .NET solution?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms, webimage

I have an `images` folder in which I have stored an image. I can see it in my file explorer, but in my .NET solution, I can only see the `images` folder. I can't see the image which is inside that folder.

[image]

Help me out in this as I am using ASP.NET web forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to see the files inside of the solution or project, you have to add them. Simply creating a folder and copying files into it will not suffice.

In Solution Explorer, Right-Click on the images folder> Add> Existing Item...
Browse for the files you want to include, and then click on 'Add'

[image]

On a side note, when adding images to your project, it is a good idea to optimize them. I've included a link below to the Visual Studio Marketplace where you can find the Image optimizer from Madz Kristensen, which can help you reduce the file size, without losing noticeable quality.

[Mads Kristensen - Image Optimizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ImageOptimizer)